# how to draw lines between relative layouts in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have three relative layouts to display billing address, shipping address and summary. I want to draw a line to seperate these layouts. How is it possible??

Comment: Did you tried something? Or you need a programmer to code?

Comment: i tried putting view in between layouts.. it didnt work .. so posted question here

Comment: So you should add your findings or the code which you tried. I makes clear that you have also did some efforts to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code between layouts to draw lines

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add view like below:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/vi_sep"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="color or image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `View` with height 1dp and give it background colour grey to separate your three layouts. (Still, I don't see the need for the relative layouts though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a view with some background and height 2dp, width match_parent in between

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
                   <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dip"
                    android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following **View** which has 1dp of height

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ImageView` with background `color or image` height 1dp 
and also you can use this image!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#ff00ff"/>
```